# Check Record Set Exists For PHP Active Record

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

In short, when I pull a record using php activerecord, I'd like to check that it exists before moving forward.  There has to be an easier way to do this as each situation seems to be different and I'm not actually sure any of them are working correctly.

For example:

```
$var = Model::find_by_pk("something");

if (!empty($var)) { ... //record exists }
```

Will that catch all exceptions or if the record returns no rows at all for a single record pull?

Then I've tried this:

```
if (count($var->errors) == 0) { ... //records exist }
```

This seems to work on resultsets, but not single record pulls. I get an exception of trying to reference an object that doesn't exist.

I see the Model::exists() but does that mean I need to go back through and change all my activerecord calls? (http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Model#methodexists)?

To sum up, what is a simple way (preferably universal and/or bullet proof) to check that a php.activerecord result has data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be enough to do

```
$var = Model::find_by_pk("something");
if($var){
    //winning
}else{
    //not found
}
```

The reason you can't do `if (count($var->errors) == 0)` is that when you don't get a hit, `$var` is not an object so you cannot check the `errors` for it.

Mind you that if you do `find` you'll get an exception if it doesn't exist, instead of just no result:

```
 try{
     $var = Model::find($id);
 }catch (\Exception $e){
      //not found
 }
```

Comment: don't mean to hijack this post, but on a similar note, how do you perform validation on the initial setup to check if the initialization was successful or not? [see](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17637739/2180697)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but be advised this is not a forum with threads you can hijack. It is all about the Q&A. Just open up a new Q, explain in detail what you mean ;)

Comment: Apologies for making it seem like a hijack. I in fact did post the question. its the 'see' text with the hyperlink to my question in stackoverflow. [here's the link to it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17637739/2180697)