# PHP ActiveRecord how to check if connection to database is successful?

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

How do I check if the initialisation was successful after I do this?

```
ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg){
    $cfg->set_model_directory('models');
    $cfg->set_connections(array(
        'development' => "mysql://root:root@localhost/blog"
        ));  
});
```

And then I go onto doing something like:

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

Just before performing the above I'd like to check if the initialization was successful.

With a **PDO object** I could do:

```
if $con ? /*execute query*/ : /*failed to connect*/
```

How could I achieve the same assurance with ActiveRecord?

Comment: Anybody got any thoughts?

Comment: What goes wrong when you jsut check the connection with `$model->connection()` ?

Comment: Hi, I don't have an object called model? I also updated my question for some more clarity.

Comment: I meant any object that extends the `Activeracord/Model` class. A quick seach also shows the `Connection::instance` static functions, maybe that helps.

Comment: Right I get what you mean. Yes, I could potentially instantiate an object and check it. My initial attempt of using `Connection::instance` failed with `class 'Connection' not found`. I will have to look into it.

Comment: you problably want to check for the right namespace...

Comment: Brilliant. You were right. Please post your comments in the answer section, So I can formally accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either check the connection from some instance you have (lets say you have got some model instantiated as `$model`), like so:

```
$model->connection();
```

You can probably do it statically, by calling the connection class

```
\Activerecord\Connection::instance();
```

Comment: And how to close that connection??